# Use Jenkins docker image can't connect github

Tags: image, docker, jenkins, github, ssh

If use jenkins official docker image: `jenkins/jenkins:alpine`, want to connect github, is it necessary to generate a ssh key under Jenkins user in the container?

I think it's necessary, due to the github document: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

But had connected to github successfully without any private/public keys under ~/.ssh path. Now can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But had connected to github successfully without any private/public keys under ~/.ssh path

For read-access of public GitHub repo, meaning for cloning/pulling, you don't need an SSH key and can use an anonymous access with an HTTPS URL.

The error message "`Permission denied (publickey)`" appears only if you are using an SSH URL.

Comment: You are right. The github side is using `read-only` permission and the access method is through `HTTPS`. Now `ssh -vT git@github.com` can get right response from github, but can't get the repo from it. Strange.

Comment: @zseikyocho possibly because Jenkins is not using the same $HOME.

Comment: It can been connected again. Thank you very much.